# Dart - Adding constant value to list from changing variable

Tags: dart

I have problem with adding list to a list.
Added position to list "pusta" do not stay constant while i change variable "row". The result should look like that: [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]. I get [[2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]. I write in DartPad.
I tried to change row to string while adding to list, but tests on Codewars do not take it as solution.

```
logisticMap(width, height, xs, ys) {

  manhDist(width, height,xs,ys, pozx, pozy){
    int x =0; 
  List<int> lista =[];
  int i=0;

  while(x<xs.length) {
    num wart = (xs[x]-pozx).abs() + (ys[x]-pozy).abs();
    lista.add(wart);
    x++;
  }
  int minimum = lista[0];

  while (i<lista.length) {
    (lista[i]<minimum) ? minimum=lista[i] : minimum;
    i++;
  }
  return minimum;
}

  int i=0;
  int j=0;
  List<int> row =[];
  List<List> pusta=[];


  if (xs.isNotEmpty) {

    while (i<height) {
      row.clear();
      while (j<width) {
        row.add(manhDist(width, height, xs,ys,j,i));
        j++;
      }
      j=0;
      pusta.add(row);
      i++;
    }

    return pusta;

  } else {
    while (j < height) {
      row.clear();
      while (i < width) {
        row.add(null);
        i++;
      }
      i = 0;
      pusta.add(row);
      j++;
    }
    return pusta;
  }
}  

void main() {
  logisticMap(3, 3, [0], [0]);
}
```

I tried to find solution in other user code, but without luck. 
I don't know where is a difference. His code work:

```
List<List<int>> logisticMap(width,height,xs,ys) {
  List<List<int>> result = [];
  for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
    List<int> rowResult = [];
    for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
        rowResult.add(closestSupplyPoint(xs, ys, j, i));
    }
    result.add(rowResult);
  }
  return result;
}

int closestSupplyPoint(xs, ys, x, y) {
  int minDistance = null;
  for (int i = 0; i < xs.length; ++i) {
    int distance = (xs[i] - x).abs() + (ys[i] - y).abs();
    if (minDistance == null || distance < minDistance) {
      minDistance = distance;
    }
  }
  return minDistance;
}
```

Comment: Properly formatting the code would make it easier to understand. I assume you are reusing a list instance instead of creating a new list, this is why modifying one list modifies others as well, while "others" is just other references to the same list.

Comment: Do you mean to replace row.clear() with list<int> row = [] ? I have done this. Effect is the same. Sorry for bad formating.

Comment: Something like that. Did you change it in both places? I didn't try to understand what your code does exactly.

Comment: Yes, and now i feel stupid. It work. It return a 2D list(matrix?) of Manhattan distance from nearest supply point. Thank you for help.